# Render string as MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have a simple Email Composer class where I get all Application Emails content from. 
In this example, it sends the products to the email.

Now, I want to **print** them as well, and **I'm trying to re-use the same method to grab the full html from the Email Composer and output it to a View.**

the controller action

```
public ActionResult PrintRules()
{
    var products = rep.ListAllProductsByCompanyId(currentCompany.company_id);
    string body = mail.GetProductRules(products);

    ViewBag.email = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
    return View();
}
```

the view is:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    string email = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.email);
}

@Html.Raw(email)

<script>
     window.print();
</script>
```

If I pass the `body` as a `Model` I do get errors on the parser, so I'm using the `ViewBag` instead.

as outputs:

- `@Html.Raw(email)` will output nothing at all
- `@Html.Raw(email.Length)` will output `17463`
- `@email` will output the code but the browser outputs it, does not parse it (image below)

What am I missing? I know it must be a really simple thing, but I'm totally blank...

---

browser output from using `@email`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@(new HtmlString(mystring))
```

or

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Stuff)
```

Comment: You should really explain that why `@Html.Raw' doesn't work and why your solution works?